How to place node to mouse position after drag and drop from outside editor with Rete.js
I am currently working with rete.js. I am kinda new to it.
I have an application with the editor on one side and then a list of button on the other side.
The list of button is not part of the editor but when i drag and drop elements from it, it triggers a function I have made that creates a node in the editor. My issue is with the positionning of the node after the drop. The editor's (0,0) coordinates are in the middle of the editor plus the issue of being able to zoom in and out that expends the amount of coordinates. And what I have access to in order to position nodes are the coordinates from my mouse in the overall screen when dropping.
I have tried to use
const { x, y, k } = area.area.transform

But I am not really sure on how to use it to translate my coordinates.
So far I have been twiking coordinates here and there to try and find a correlation but my brain is not braining.
Thanks in advance for any help

I faced the same problem. and I did the following.
function dragAndDropToAddNode(
  areaPlugin: AreaPlugin<Schemes, AreaExtra>,
  editor: NodeEditor<Schemes>
){
  const containerEle = areaPlugin.container;
  containerEle.addEventListener('drop',async (e) => {
    const nodeName = e.dataTransfer.getData('node');
    let newNode: Schemes['Node'];
    if(nodeName == 'message'){
      newNode = new Message('vinod');
    } else{
      return;
    }
    await editor.addNode(newNode);
    // translating the node to the drop location.----------------s
    const {x, y, k} = areaPlugin.area.transform;
    const box = containerEle.getBoundingClientRect();
    await areaPlugin.translate(newNode.id, {
      x: (e.clientX - box.left - x)/k - newNode.width/2,
      y: (e.clientY - box.top - y)/k,
    });
    //   ------------------------------------------------------------
  })
  containerEle.addEventListener('dragover',(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer!.dropEffect = 'copy';
  })
}

and ofcourse you need to add a draggable element in the element to drop.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
